# Eventbus v.s. MessageQueue, which is better to broadcast market data in algo trading scenario?

Tags: mvvm-light, message-queue, zeromq, trading, netmq

I am trying to decide which tech to use to broadcast my real-time market data to my trading strategies. The scenario is as follow,

I have multiple trading strategies subscribe to different tickers, as the market data for certain ticker is received, I will broadcast this ticker's market data to the strategies. The listening trading strategies will act up on the received market data.

I have two type of implementation in mind,

1) is to use an event bus like the `Messenger` class provided by `mvvmlight` ,

2) another way is to use a Message queue system such as `ZeroMQ`(`NetMQ`)

Noted that both market data api and trading strategies are on the same machine, so there is no network involved.

Which is more suitable for my case?

Comment: Hi, how about deciding on the value of answers and selecting the best one? This is how StackOverflow works, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to distribute market data, Pub-Sub pattern in ZeroMQ (NetMQ) is more better.

Answer (score 0):

### Initial remark

With all due respect, one shall first define metrics of "suitability", otherwise the question has no rationale.

### How to decide?

If it were my Project,
I would weight these ingredients:
- conceptual **capability of `( N + M )` fail-safe architectures** - both **`ZeroMQ`** + **`nanomsg`** are capable
**- linearity of performance scaleability** - `ZeroMQ` + `nanomsg` are fabulous in this
- code-base
- width of language bindings ( for increased economies of ROI )
- costs of adaptations + learning curve ( accross the whole team / company / 3rd party vendors )

---

### Is `PUB/SUB` the best option?

<sub>Remember the glorious **Maslow's hammer:**</sub>

> “When the only tool you have is a hammer, every problem begins to resemble a nail.

While **`PUB/SUB`** might initially attract your attention, you might later realise it's devastating powers on the performance due to the `SUB`-side filtering.

If you do not headbang in this in testing, be happy not to meet this at a late stage after the architecture is in place...